# How to include/require a portion of text from a file?

Tags: php, html

Each page of my website has a related famous quote before the footer. I would like to write all quotes in a html/txt/php file and from there include the relevant one on each page. When trying to use require or include, it doesn't work because they are designed to call the contents of a whole file, not just a portion of it. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide more details... For example, how do you want to choose a quote, how do you want to address this in your code, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your files with quote (eg `quotes.php`) you can do something like:

```
<?php

return [
    'q1' => 'quote one here',
    'q2' => 'quote two',
];
```

In other php file you can do:

```
<?php

$quotes = require 'path/to/quotes.php';
// now in `$quotes` you have an array and can:
echo $quotes['q1'];
```

Comment: At first it didn't work. Then I added the closing " ?>" and now it work's like a charm. Very thankful.

Answer (score 1):

Here are your options:

1. If they must be in a txt file, store the quotes with a separation symbol like "|"

> **quotes.txt**
>
> Every day is a new day|To be, or not to be|Love yourself

Then, on your page where one of these quotes will be displayed, define the index of the quote you would like to be displayed, then include a script that will use this index and pull out the related quote:

> **dashboard.php** (or whatever)

```
$quoteIndex = 0;
include_once('quote.php');
```

> **quote.php**

```
$quotes = file_get_contents('quotes.txt');
$quotes = explode('|', $quotes);
// make sure the index is set and that it isn't out of range
if(!isset($quoteIndex) || $quoteIndex > count($quotes) - 1) {
    $quoteIndex = 0;
}
echo $quotes[$quoteIndex];
```

Now, on **dashboard.php**, the first quote in the file will be printed out.

2. If you don't mind them being in a PHP file, simply create an array inside **quote.php** instead of pulling them from a text file

> **quote.php**

```
$quotes = ['Every day is a new day', 'To be, or not to be', 'Love yourself'];
// make sure the index is set and that it isn't out of range
if(!isset($quoteIndex) || $quoteIndex > count($quotes) - 1) {
    $quoteIndex = 0;
}
echo $quotes[$quoteIndex];
```

Doing it in this way would also allow you to easily recognise which quotes are for which by using key->value pairs like so:

> **dashboard.php**

```
$pageName = 'dashboard';
include_once('quote.php');
```

> **quote.php**

```
$quotes = [
    'dashboard' => 'Every day is a new day',
    'home' => 'To be, or not to be',
    'news' => 'Love yourself'
];
// make sure the page name is set and exists
if(!isset($pageName) || !isset($quotes[$pageName])) {
    echo "Page name provided for quote incorrect";
} else {
    echo $quotes[$pageName];
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Thanks a lot iJamesPHP2, the solution offered by u_mulder entered first and I tried it first, working very well for me, so I didn't try yours. But I am very thankful for your help anyway!